# How do you find a substring of a string in python using no built-in function or slicing

Tags: python, string, substring, slice

I'm trying to work on a basic python program that is to find a substring of a string in python but the challenge was I can't use built functions or slicing.

```
MAINSTRING = raw_input('Enter a string : ')

print 'You entered %s' %MAINSTRING

isSubString = raw_input('Enter the substring : ')

print 'You entered %s' %isSubString

if isSubString in MAINSTRING:
    print isSubString + " is a substring of " + MAINSTRING
```

It works but I can't use `in` syntax which is the frustrating part. I also know to use the slicing method in python but my challenge was to break it to the basics.

Sorry for being so vague, but I just got a hint.

The complete code consist of two 'for' loops, one for the string and one for the substring

Comment: Would you be allowed to use the regular expressions module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: what are the things that you can use ?

Comment: You can iterate over each letter in a string with `for letter in str`, it's all you need, from here you will have to work.

Comment: sorry for being so vague, i added something I can use which is 'for' loops.

Comment: Can you use `range`? Can you use `len`? Can you use `enumerate`? Can you write your own functions? Can you use `yield`? Can you create exact replicas of `range` and `len` and `enumerate`? Can you use string indexing? Can you use lists? Can you use `str.join`? Can you use `str.__eq__`? Can you use `str.__add__`? Can you use `str.__iter__`?

Comment: It also might be interesting to check out the Python implementation of the Boyer-Moore string search algorithm which is a more efficient alrogithm than iterating through each letter of a string, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: yes, I believe so. I know that the final code consist of 'range(len())' in the 'for' loop. I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Ah ha, it must be a trick question, then. If your teacher says you can't use built in functions, and that you must use `range` and `len`, the answer is "there is no logically consistent way to obey both requirements"

Comment: Also, if you can’t use `in`, you can’t use a for loop. And if you can’t use slicing, you also cannot use a while loop (since you cannot access the characters).

Comment: I want to downvote your teacher’s task.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid anything other than for loops and a function you could do it like this although I have no idea why. Also you will have to use `in` which is pointed out in the comments. If a letter in the mainstring matches the first letter in the substring then add it to the temp string `t`, then go to the next letters in each and see if they match. If the temp string equals the substring then it exists and it will return.

```
def substring(ss, s):
    x = 0
    t = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == ss[x]:
            t += ss[x]
            if t == ss:
                return s
            x+=1
        else:
            x = 0
            t = ""
```

Comment: This technically both uses `in` and slicing which is possibly disallowed by OP.

Comment: @poke yes I know but you can't write for loops without `in` as you pointed out above and I'm going to assume OP can't use slicing like `s[4:8]` rather than what I added which I look at as indexing.

Comment: (My comment was not really a serious complaint since, as we noted in the question comments, the literal requirements make it impossible; this is a good answer)

Comment: @poke I just tried to write an answer with the least amount of built in functions as I could. It's a dumb assignment regardless

Comment: @poke: There are two different forms of `in`, one that's an implicit call to `__contains__` (`if x in y`) and the other that's an implicit use of the iterator protocol (an initial call to `__iter__` followed by calls to `next` (Py2)/`__next__` (Py3). You could ban one without banning the other, though it's silly.

Comment: @SirParselot: You can write loops without `in`, it just results in incredibly unPythonic code most of the time (when implementing a C-style `for` loop using separate initializers, increments, and a `while` loop).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I thought I had learned at one point that you could do it that way but I've never seen it done so I just assumed I was dreaming. Either way I'm leaving what I've got.

Comment: @SirParselot: Oh, it's horrible way to do it. The only time I do stuff like that is when I'm using `EAFP` patterns to consume a collection that might be being filled (or drained) from another thread (or mutated within the loop itself) with atomic behavior, e.g. `while True:`, `try:`, `x = mydeque.popleft()`, `except IndexError:`, `break`, `rest of processing goes here`. And even then, it's not looping by numeric indices. I think I've looped by index using a `while` loop once in my entire life (in a case where the increment was inconsistent from loop to loop, so `range` didn't cut it).